# How to implement the row clicked in Xamarin Forms TableView Cell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following tableview set up in XAML for Xamarin Forms:

```
<TableView Intent="Menu">
   <TableRoot>
      <TableSection Title="Categories">
         <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="20,0,20,0">
               <Label Text="Category" XAlign="Center"/>
               <Label Text=">" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" XAlign="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </TableSection>
   </TableRoot> 
</TableView>
```

Can anyone let me know how to implement the clicking of the row to open another content page xamarin forms? Or do I have to separately implement in the iOS side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Xamarin Documentation about the [TapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/).

You can apply that method here as well.
I'm not completely sure if you can apply it directly to the `ViewCell` but you should be able to do it on the `StackLayout`.

So it would be something like:

```
<TableView Intent="Menu">
   <TableRoot>
      <TableSection Title="Categories">
         <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="20,0,20,0">
               <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                   <TapGestureRecognizer
                       Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                       NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
               </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

               <Label Text="Category" XAlign="Center"/>
               <Label Text=">" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" XAlign="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </TableSection>
   </TableRoot> 
</TableView>
```

And then of course implement the event method.

Answer (score 2):

You could also add the Tapped method to the ViewCell itself.

Like this:

```
<ViewCell Tapped="Handle_Cell_Tapped">
</View>
```

Then write your Handle_Cell_Tapped event handler in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ItemTappedEventArgsConverter` from Xamarin.Comunity.Toolkit to do this. It's pretty simple and straight forward. Here is a link to the documentation and there are also some samples.

[Xamarin Community Toolkit - ItemTappedEventArgsConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/itemtappedeventargsconverter)